# Problem using Browsershot and Puppeteer in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I'm encountering an error when attempting to use Browsershot and Puppeteer to capture a screenshot of a Blade view.

The command ""C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe"
"D:\Work_Folders\Portal\portal-project\portal-backend\vendor\spatie\browsershot\src/../bin/browser.cjs"
"{""url"":""http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/api/map"",""action"":""screenshot"",""options"":{""type"":""png"",""path"":""D:\Work_Folders\Portal\portal-project\portal-backend\public\images/reports/map_screenshot.png"",""args"":[],""viewport"":{""width"":800,""height"":600}}}""
failed.

Exit Code: 1(General error)

Working directory: D:\Work_Folders\Portal\portal-project\portal-backend\public

## Output:

## Error Output:

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdtemp 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'mkdtemp',
path: 'undefined\temp\puppeteer_dev_chrome_profile-XXXXXX'
}

```
        $mapUrl = route('map');

        $filePath = public_path('images/reports/map_screenshot.png');

        Browsershot::url($mapUrl)
            ->setNodeBinary('C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe')
            ->setNpmBinary('C:/Program Files/nodejs/npm')
            ->setTempDir(public_path('images/temp')) // Set the temporary directory explicitly
            ->save($filePath);

        return view('map', compact('locations', 'mapUrl'));
```

"dependencies": {
"puppeteer": "^22.6.0"
}

"wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows": "0.12.2.3"